# Zend2 DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to FALSE but it's not

Tags: php, zend-framework2, qr-code, dompdf

I spend few days working on this problem. So I am using Zend framework 2 added a module dompdf to create pdfs and qr code creator, qr is working fine with basic html page, but when I'm trying to move it into dompdf it shows an error

[image]

DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to FALSE

I've changed it in dompdf_config.inc.php and dompdf_config.custom.inc.php to be 100% sure, but it shows the same error. If I will change the link from qr code to a static pic it will work fine, and I think there is a problem with DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR because it shows the wrong path "C:\Windows\TEMP"

Comment: half way there, image_cache.cls.php 
line 55 :
$enable_remote = $dompdf->get_option("enable_remote");

enable_remote is an empty string, and acts as false. Solved by adding 
$dompdf->set_option("enable_remote",true); before line 55. in case anyone will find a better solution I will leave this question opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config/autoload/global.php put the following:

```
<?php


use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

return array(
    'dompdf_module' => array(
        'enable_remote' => true
    ),
);
```